# Why is my DateTime Incorrect?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to compare times and I want to use the phone current time to use in math. Now im certain if I can get this string to work then my app will be 100% complete.

```
DateTime phonecurrentime =
    new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute);
```

The only problem is.... -

```
testbox.Text = phonecurrentime.ToString("dd hh:mm");
```

Displays an incorrect time of:28 12:00 -????? When the day really was 30th and the time as 01:30

How can I get it display the correct day?

Comment: The current time is DateTime.Now. There's no need to create it the way you are.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why create an instance using constructor when phone current time is `Now`. Simply use `DateTime.Now`

```
DateTime phonecurrentime = DateTime.Now;

testbox.Text = phonecurrentime.ToString("dd hh:mm"); //30 01:30
```

You should also use AM/PM because hh will show time in 00-12 hour format. Your Datetime format should be `"dd hh:mm tt"`. In that case string will be 30 01:30 PM if its second half of day.

Comment: Debugger breaks on with that         DateTime phonecurrentime = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute);

Comment: Yep. In that case no need to use AM/PM. For more on DateTime Formats in C# read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx.

Answer (score 5):

The call your using to create your date is

```
DateTime(int year, int month, int day);
```

Your code should read (if you don't care about the year, month)

```
DateTime phonecurrentime =
    new DateTime(0, 0, DateTime.Today.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Seconds);
```

if you do care about year/month

```
DateTime phonecurrentime =
    new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Seconds);
```

Or simply

```
DateTime phonecurrentime = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Error 1 'System.DateTime' does not contain a constructor that takes 5 arguments

Comment: Correct. Added the seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong constructor.

```
DateTime(int year, int month, int day)
```

Three integers in the constructor is the above signature. You want the longer version:

```
DateTime(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second)
```

Like this:

```
DateTime phonecurrentime =
new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, 0);
```

Or simply:

```
DateTime phonecurrenttime = DateTime.Now;
```